# Subclass UIButton: Property not initialized at super.init call

Tags: uibutton, subclassing

I'm trying to subclass a UIButton so I can do custom animations on them but I'm running into a init problem

Property 'self.originalWidth' not initialized at super.init call

Here's my code:

```
   import UIKit

enum ButtonType {
    case newGameButton
    case showStatsButton
    case addTeamButton
    case addUserButton
}

class LSS_Button: UIButton {

    var myButtonType:ButtonType?
    var originalWidth:CGFloat
    var originalHeight:CGFloat


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       fatalError("Something went terribly wrong with init on LSS_Button")
    }


    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.originalWidth = self.frame.size.width
        self.originalHeight = self.frame.size.height
    }
```

How can I resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Forgot to add, if I put self.originalWidth = ... above the super.init then I get this error:

'self' used before super.init call

Answer (score 0):

Dang it, figured out like 5 seconds later:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {


    self.originalWidth = frame.size.width
    self.originalHeight = frame.size.height        

     super.init(frame: frame)


}
```